# Power supply of a project

Tags: raspberry-pi, sparkfun

i'm thinking of making a project similar to the one you'll see in the picture lower: i want to control a remote control of a Velux with a Raspberry PI based on some data of temperature, rain, wind and so on.

The thing that i don't understand is what is the red board to the right (by sparkfun) that (i think) is giving power supply to the relays and the remote control (it needs 4.5V). Can you tell me what it is and what it does exactly?

Thank you in advance

[image: Image of the project]

Comment: Do you have a link to the project? It's kind of difficult to tell by inspection; but like you said: it looks like a power supply.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have the link to the project but it doesn't say anything about it, that's why I could't understand what it was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8376

> SparkFun Breadboard Power Supply USB - 5V/3.3V
>   PRT-08376 RoHS
>
> Description: A very simple breadboard power supply kit that takes power from any USB port and outputs a fuse protected and regulated 3.3V.

Judging from the image there is also an unfused direct 5V output, directly taken from USB. Beware not to draw too much current from USB, a normal PC cannot source more than 500mA.

[image]

Looks pretty similar to the picture you provided:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just couldn't find it! So basically this board is used to give the power supply to the remote from USB and it has a voltage regulator that supplies 3.3V or 5V, assuring that the current doesn't exceed 500mA, right?

Comment: 5V is directly from USB. 3V3 is through the regulator. Total current for both cannot exceed 500mA or your PC may shut down the port (or the motherboard might get fried).